# Cannot run command in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoexport

**Problem Statement**

I cannot run a MongoDB command in Mongoose's `model.db.db.admin().command()` method. It gives me the error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: no such command: '0'`

---

**What I have tried**

- I have tried running it in my CLI and MongoDB Compass Shell to see if it is an error with my command, and it seems it is, and it gives me this error:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ";" (1:15)`

`mongoexport -c appointment -o appointments_2021_04_10_9_52.json`

- I have googled for many hours trying to find out how to fix these errors and run a proper command in Mongoose.

**Please note**: I am quite new to Mongoose/NodeJS and MongoDB. Also, I am running MongoDB locally.

---

**My Code (app.js)**

```
app.get('/exportAllAppoinments', (req, res) => {

    mongoose.connect(mongoUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }).then(() => {

        const dateTime = moment().format('yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm');
        console.log(dateTime);

        modelAppointment.db.db.admin().command('mongoexport --collection=appointment --out=appointments_' + dateTime + '.json').then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        });
    },
        err => console.log(err)
    );
});
```

---

**Expected Results**

Mongoose should export the entire collection and send the file back to the frontend.

---

**Actual Results**

It does nothing and gives me an error as shown in the beginning.

Comment: With `--out=appointments_' + dateTime + '.json'` the file is stored locally on your server. Maybe try `--out=-` which sends the output to STDOUT. Also you did not specify any database (but maybe it is already part of the connection URI).

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It already knows which database it needs to run on (since the model is connected to the specific database). Also, I have tried what you said with the `--out=-` where there is a `-` in it, and it didn't work. Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`modelAppointment.db.db.admin().command()` is used to submit a [database command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/#database-commands) to MongoDB.

[mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoexport/#mongoexport) is a command line tool, not a database command.

You might try using `exec` from child_process to run the command.